# ¿Cómo imprimir la cadena de texto "Buenos dias" incrementalmente de derecha a izquierda usando for anidados?

Tags: java

[image: resultado]

```
 public static String piramide() {
        String salida = "";
        String palabra = "Buenos dias";
        
        for (int i = 10; i >= 0; --i) {
            for (int j = 10; j >= i; --j) {
                salida +=palabra.charAt(j);      
            }
            salida += "\n";
        }
        return salida;
    }
```

Que retorne la hilera de la clase en una hilera desplegable empezando por la última letra en la primera fila, con las 2 últimas letras en segunda línea, hasta completar la hilera H. Por ejemplo: H = “Buenos
días”, ver cuadro.

Answer (score 2):

Podrias hacer uso de [reverse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#reverse()) de la clase StringBuffer o bien puedes usar StringBuilder ,junto con una nueva variable auxiliar que concatene los datos invertidos que ya obtuviste

Ejemplo

```
String palabra="Buenos dias";
    String aux="";
    String aux1="";
    
    for (int i =palabra.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {   
         for (int j=palabra.length()-1;j>=i;j-- ) {   
            aux+=palabra.charAt(j);     
         }
         StringBuffer sbr = new StringBuffer(aux);
         aux="";
         aux1+=sbr.reverse()+"\n";
    }
    System.out.println(aux1);
    }
```

salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Es un poco lioso ya que tu código lo hace bien pero esta planteado de otra manera, puesto que el anidado pilla la primera y lo coloca en la primera posición, y así con la segunda, etc. No es lo que nos interesa en este caso, podrías hacerlo igual anidando pero luego arreglar las posiciones en las que deberían estar o puedes anidarlo todo e ir rebajando para luego darle la vuelta con un .reverse().

```
StringBuilder salida = new StringBuilder();
    String palabra = "Buenos dias";

    for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 10; j >= i; j--) {
            salida.append(palabra.charAt(j));
        }
        salida.append("\n");
    }

    return salida.reverse().toString();
}
```

Ya que usas un StringBuilder usa sus funciones de juntarlo siendo el append y luego en el return le indicas que le de la vuelta. ¿Porque? Por que sin el reverse aparecería de esta manera:

```
said soneuB
said soneu
said sone
said son
said so
said s
said 
said
sai
sa
s
```

Que curiosamente es parecido al resultado de tu código solo que al revés. Por ello es un poco lioso pero una vez le pillas el truco lo puedes sacar como quieras.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres usar una función(método) que retorne cada fila, vas a tener que hacer un bucle dentro del método (posiblemente sea el método main) que llama a `piramide()`; otra opción es imprimir la cadena `salida` dentro del mismo método `piramide()`.

```
public static void piramide() {
        String salida = "";
        String palabra = "Buenos dias";       
        
        for (int i = palabra.length()-1; i >= 0; --i) {
            salida =palabra.charAt(i)+salida;
            System.out.println(salida);            
        }        
}
```